# scala how to concurrently run X number of functions at a time in a for loop

Tags: scala

```
//queries a List[String] type
queries.foreach(query => {
  devHive.execute(query)
})
```

I have a simple `for loop` like this, how would I change this so it would concurrently execute 100 functions at a time? I don't care if it waits for all 100 to finish then execute the next 100, or executes another as each finishes, whatever it is, it must be simpler to implement.

```
error: value forEach is not a member of List[Array[String]]
queries.grouped(100).toList.forEach(queriesChunk => {
```

Comment: @jwvh But how would I limit this to say, 100 at a time? I have 100,000 items in this and don't to execute them all at once. I want to execute say, 100 at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With something like this the chunks would be processed synchronously:

```
queries.grouped(100).toList().foreach(queriesChunk => {
    queriesChunk.par.foreach(query => devHive.execute(query))
})
```

but the chunk content would be processed in parallel.

Comment: Why would this code get processed in parallel? `queriesChunk.par.forEach(query => devHive.execute(query))` this would cause sequential execution of `devHive.execute(query)`, no?

Comment: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#par:ParRepr

Comment: Okay, thanks, didn't know what `.par` was.  This is great!

Comment: I get the following error `error: value forEach is not a member of List[Array[String]]
  queries.grouped(100).toList.forEach(queriesChunk => {`

Comment: Strange. I checked it and if queries is a `List[String]` then `queries.grouped(100).toList` return a `List[List[String]]` as it should.

Comment: `foreach()` not `forEach()`